# How can I add ACL permissions to users?. in Kinvey

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kinvey

I have this. It does not work. in others collections work fine with save, but this collection (users) not have save.

```
 Kinvey.User.get('546264a54b9cb82c61003727').then(
 function(response) {

        $scope.user = response;

        var acl = new Kinvey.Acl($scope.user);

        acl.addWriter($scope.currentcontact.Contact.contact.user_id);   
    acl.addReader($scope.currentcontact.Contact.contact.user_id);   

var promise = Kinvey.User.update($scope.user, {
        success: function() {
                console.log("...done");
          }
});
```

Comment: IS there an error message?

Comment: Looks like your question was answered by Kinvey on their forums..?
https://support.kinvey.com/discussion/201272452/how-do-i-can-add-acl-permissions-to-users-edit-acl-in-users